# Two Different Python Version in QGIS and in Macbook

Tags: qgis, python, scp

How can I fix this and make sure that I'm installing Scipy, Matplotlib, GDAL, and Numpy in the correct python version if my QGIS 3.8 uses Python 3.6 and my Macbook Terminal is using Python 2.7? I'm trying to fix this for the SCP plugin.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Thank you so much - I realized it too that I have to write Python 3 install _________ when I want to specify something in the terminal. I found the answer on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42502614/run-python-3-6-in-terminal-on-mac

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
python3 --version
```

or

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3 --version
```